# Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) - startScan([service]) is not returning devices

Tags: android, typescript, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using Android and "cordova-plugin-ble-central": "^1.4.4"

The method startScan([]) with empty service is returning devices. But when I add a service no device is discovered.

I tried to connect to one of the devices so that I can be sure that I'm using the right service.

These are the services:

0: "1800"

1: "1801"

2: "6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e"

When I try to call the startScan method with one of the services nothing is discovered

Comment: Do these devices announce these services in their BLE advertisement? Try a tool like [NRF connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) to find out.

Comment: @Risto I tried using NRF connect and yes, I can see these services in their BLE advertisement. Is it possible that I'm calling the service in the wrong way? 
Do I have to use a provider or I can create a string in my function and use it locally?

Comment: can you show us the advertisement data?

Comment: These are screenshots from NRF connect app
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/AM-JKLU7QSkLybcDsraiHPftIjdcs472PgAc1tuowcDtTj91PCGJuuZlJdH_h--67RA4NQuSV2tpZxLYExm7rU7haDTnSr0NF1AhFgfVDFVJWv6SdTBmaByUBgPANChONNb19rll4TYPtwAD7LP9wGdh_Yl-Tg=w452-h903-no?authuser=0

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/AM-JKLWTpZgf0pNIV6cJRXt7Cdg_PhP_PUKfgmlJGgfSpgoBiidAWUpk5_1Gg-jNfP3MHvgZCAtvTIHjkaPHgnRHVAksSKcBr8wm8wTFY0vKXyHx3CvjWtiKO66SyjjIy4idfJRtMlQWdTG-6qe4QsnGOTG2rQ=w452-h903-no?authuser=0

Comment: These are screenshots from the console from my app

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/AM-JKLUJqugfhf_tYLUYYgWc9uZUeplVCbHdkCZmBdPfiH-jUxsMUcWYcv1XP-PKUySFRqoHAdGPDggYuxPghTKo4BiF-2nbIMGFaSEGL2HrbXTLpqWkO06UJmD9yrGSaVzNbGxv5KWcMsGs9BKClXP5tpvDVw=w1183-h332-no?authuser=0

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/AM-JKLUyxz_3_U8aIuwYtpvSwWaTUrniOe-YSr54-o73dFXdW4lRVPM08K2PohMuzLPyl2yH22QT3ZmUN7XyZZ9HqMf4cskoWnuuUH1726UstId1RM8RmuBqrtSaOC_MdHn3pJGtczlgOd-ge-yfJ2NLwZFwTg=w1163-h288-no?authuser=0

Comment: What you show is the info that is available after connection and successful service discovery. After a scan, only the data advertised by your devices is available. Example:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qiX-O96bK9m3_j3ELU0AirgSr3BVnlx7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Okay, so according to this screenshot:
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pw/AM-JKLWlpbbzN0sKVbdXYf3Di_ld7rK8sd2WmtweFP9bSqRWctGp48K7WI7z8VN_8SCuzvYIaM2ySTjuc4ScE5Or96HaEku_kuyIjb6vmFjzUy6plIm3HMZdnRMM_-yZSiWyxM0Fs00PvUpQPQ96mwcfnlh29A=w442-h883-no?authuser=0
my device is not advertising any data, is that right?
Is that mean that I won't be able to find the devices with startScan([service])
My devices are BPUCK ID 000E36 and BPUCK ID 000E35

Comment: Judging by your screenshot, I would agree that your devices do not advertise any service. Each manufacturer decides whether and what his device advertises. So yes, it's 'normal'.